# How to only display certain options in select tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

How do I only display certain options depending on the value in a select tag?

```
 function key(id){
     var selectValue = document.getElementById('names').value
        = document.carmakes.cars.selectedIndex
        var selectOption = $("#names option:selected").val();
 }

<select size='5' name='carmakes' onchange='key(id)'>
    <option selected='selected' value="-1">Car makes</option>
    <option>BMW</option>
    <option>Audi</option>
</select>

<select required='required' size='5' type='text' id='names'>
<option selected="selected" value="0" >Car names</option>
<option value="1">X5</option>
<option value="2">Q5</option>
```

Comment: Depending on which select, which select option to be selected?

Comment: Can you explain little bit more , its kinda not clear.

Comment: Do you mean for example if they choose _BMW_ in `carmakes` then only show _X5_ in `names`? And only show _Q5_ if they choose _Audi_?

Comment: You need to store additional information either in javascript variable or in data-* attribute. Otherwise there are no means to tell if a car belongs to an exact maker.

Comment: @Rhumborl yes! Do you know how?

Answer (score 1):

check this: http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/select-box-change-dependent-options-dynamically

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8' />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){

//let's create arrays
var chocolates = [
    {display: "Dark chocolate", value: "dark-chocolate" }, 
    {display: "Milk chocolate", value: "milk-chocolate" }, 
    {display: "White chocolate", value: "white-chocolate" },
    {display: "Gianduja chocolate", value: "gianduja-chocolate" }];

var vegetables = [
    {display: "Broccoli", value: "broccoli" }, 
    {display: "Cabbage", value: "cabbage" }, 
    {display: "Carrot", value: "carrot" },
    {display: "Cauliflower", value: "cauliflower" }];

var icecreams = [
    {display: "Frozen yogurt", value: "frozen-yogurt" }, 
    {display: "Booza", value: "booza" }, 
    {display: "Frozen yogurt", value: "frozen-yogurt" },
    {display: "Ice milk", value: "ice-milk" }];

//If parent option is changed
$("#parent_selection").change(function() {
        var parent = $(this).val(); //get option value from parent 

        switch(parent){ //using switch compare selected option and populate child
              case 'chocolates':
                list(chocolates);
                break;
              case 'vegetables':
                list(vegetables);
                break;              
              case 'icecreams':
                list(icecreams);
                break;  
            default: //default child option is blank
                $("#child_selection").html('');  
                break;
           }
});

//function to populate child select box
function list(array_list)
{
    $("#child_selection").html(""); //reset child options
    $(array_list).each(function (i) { //populate child options 
        $("#child_selection").append("<option value=\""+array_list[i].value+"\">"+array_list[i].display+"</option>");
    });
}

});
</script>

</head>
<body>  
<div class="wrapper">
Category : <select name="parent_selection" id="parent_selection">
    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option value="chocolates">Chocolates</option>
    <option value="vegetables">Vegetables</option>
    <option value="icecreams">Ice cream</option>
</select>
<select name="child_selection" id="child_selection">
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

or this: http://simpleweb.github.io/jquery-dependent-selects/

Answer (score 0):

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/20omnz2c/

```
$('#carmakes').on('change', function () {
    var selected = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if (selected != '0') {
        $('#names').show();
        $('#names option').hide();  //hide all options initially
        $('#names option:eq(0)').show();  //show the first option
        $('#names option.' + selected).show();  //show options with the right class        
    } else {
        $('#names').hide();     
        $('#names option').hide();        
    }
});
```